# how do you migrate to api 1 in battlesnake?

Tags: python, api

Battlesnake said my battlesnake is using version 0 of the Battlesnake API.
It said this version is now deprecated and in the future will not be supported. the reference page told me to implement the HTTP calls to play the game.

here's an original code in python:

```
    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    def index(self):
        return {
    "apiversion": "1",
    "author": "your-username",
    "color": "#888888",
    "head": "default",
    "tail": "default"
    } 
    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
    def start(self):
        data = cherrypy.request.json
        print("START")
        return "ok"
    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    def move(self):
        data = cherrypy.request.json
        possible_moves = ["up", "down", "left", "right"]
        move = random.choice(possible_moves)
        print(f"MOVE: {move}")
        return {"move": move}
    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
    def end(self):
        data = cherrypy.request.json
        print("END")
        return "ok"
```

and the instruction said this:

**Step 1: Implement Root Endpoint
The old POST /ping endpoint is now deprecated and can be removed from your Battlesnake.  Instead, Battlesnakes must implement a new GET / endpoint that will return metadata about the Battlesnake. This is now how snakes can be customized and where they will will identify their supported API version.

{
"apiversion": "1",
"author" : "my_user_name",
"color": "#888888",
"head" : "default",
"tail": "default"
}
Step 2: Update /Start Endpoint
Any customization data in the POST /start endpoint is ignored by the game engine for API Version 1 Battlesnakes. You can remove any payload your are currently sending in response to a the /start  request.**

I was not able to understand how to make the changes :(

Comment: Not a direct answer, but Battlesnake has an official starter project for Python that you can use as an example or as a template: https://github.com/battlesnakeofficial/starter-snake-python

Comment: Apologies that you had to wait so long for a response on this! I recommend joining us on Discord as there the community is much more active there than on StackOverflow: https://play.battlesnake.com/discord/